# why this route dont work correctly?

Tags: cakephp, cakephp-1.3

i follow this steps to configure my site on the host and it is work on this link

```
http://alashera.3owl.com/
```

/// **steps** ///
first i move all folders from myprojectfolder to public_html
second i remove myprojectfolder
third i move webroot folder from app to public_html and change path from index.php

/// **one problem** ///
but something wrong need to correct..when i clicked at any link to
enter to any class into controller it give me this error
[image]
 i guess this error because i remove projectfolder (tet) but not sure....

**one example :**

before uploaded my project ..i used this links to enter to this classes in localhost like this

```
http://localhost/tet/galleries/
http://localhost/tet/articles/
```

after uploaded project and removed (tet) folder i use this links  ..

```
http://alashera.3owl.com/galleries
http://alashera.3owl.com/articles
```

so why server cant see controllers classes..thanks

Comment: Check your server logs for a more detailed description of your problem.

Comment: i dont find server logs button in cpanel..this image from cpanel http://www14.0zz0.com/2012/01/31/03/967192169.jpg

Answer (score 0):

Looks like mod_rewrite is NOT working in your server.

Check if http://alashera.3owl.com/index.php/galleries (& http://alashera.3owl.com/index.php/articles) works. If that works, then I would suggest you check the following.

- Is mod_rewrite enabled on the server?
- Have you uploaded the relevant .htaccess or added appropriate rewrite rules to your virtual host configuration?
- Is execution of .htaccess permitted in your server?

Comment: **yes it is enabled **i upload all my project files without any change or add to any .htacess files **i am not sure but i think it is permitted...your link works but without including for header or footer or any design files why? and how to work this files without /index.php/

Comment: The best option will be to check with your hosting provider to confirm whether they support '.htaccess' and 'mod_rewrite' rules.

If it turns out that they do not support it, then the alternative is to configure cakePHP not to use mod_rewrite.

Comment: StackKrish...what can i do now  if it is not support or support  htaccess ...what code i should write..let us try please?

Answer (score 0):

thanks for every one help me the correct answer with full steps is

1. move app, cake, plugins, vendors folder into your hosting root folder. It is user root folder on your hosting
2. delete .htaccess and index.php on cakephp root folder
3. move /app/webroot/*.* to /public_html folder
4. delete empty /app/webroot folder
5. edit /public_html/index.php to point to the ‘cake’ and ‘app’ directories. For example my public_html path for my domain is /home/myhost/public_html, so i point

   - ROOT to look at /home/myhost
   - APP_DIR to look at /home/myhost/app
   - CAKE_CORE_INCLUDE_PATH to look at /home/myhost/cake
6. edit this line on /public_html/index.php with your appropriate path

   ```
   <?php
   if (!defined('ROOT')) {
   define('ROOT', DS.'home'.DS.'myhost');
   }
   if (!defined('APP_DIR')) {
   define('APP_DIR', 'app');
   }
   if (!defined('CAKE_CORE_INCLUDE_PATH')) {
   define('CAKE_CORE_INCLUDE_PATH', DS.'home'.DS.'myhost');
   }
   ```

   ?>

7-
2. Alter 1 .htaccess file
For the fix to work, modify your app/webroot/ .htaccess file to read the following:

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c> 
    RewriteEngine On 
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d 
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f 
    RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /index.php?url=$1 [QSA,L] 
</IfModule>
```

8- change the home page from config/route
9-put database information from config/database